# Django form file field not set to None if no file uploaded

Tags: django, forms, file

Given this model

```
class ScrapbookItem(models.Model):
    scrapbook = models.ForeignKey(Scrapbook)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/scrapbook", blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

class ScrapbookItemDesignIdeaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ScrapbookItem
        fields = ['scrapbook', 'comment']
```

When I submit the form, the photo field is not being set to None, why would that be?

Comment: what is it being set to?

Comment: it's being set to empty, but I would expect it to be None.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that it's because you've got `blank=True` in your field definition. You probably don't need this, since you've got a default.

Comment: Sorry I think you have misunderstood my question